# ASP.Net 3.5 website project VS web application project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web, web-applications

I have an interesting scenario: - Site has 209,000+ pages. - Evertime a user submits a new article/item a new page is generated and if it has a refernece to one of the existing pages then that page is also re-generated and saved. - A windows service is looking after the generation of pages which creates a page(file) in the site directory. - The purpose of pre-generated pages was to save requesting data from the database as 75% times data will never be updated and having a pre-generated file on the FS saves processing and memory.

It has been working very well but we are concerned now...

The problem is the disk space is running out and if we restart the server it takes a while for site to compile and run and as volume increases we think this will cause us serious problems.

Is there a way to have pre-compiled site and we can still generate pages? (the generated pages all inherit from one class and they have custom controls)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please elaborate when you say "pre-generated" do you mean that the content of the page is stored in the database then your render the page out once in the service then save it to the file system so you don't need to have any type of content management system db interaction when users browse your site? Later you say procompiled, are you reference where all of the aspx pages in your site are just marker pages for IIS? If that's the case how do you recompile your site while it's live?

Comment: dude, not to be mean, but your concern should not be what type of project to use, it should be how to fire the guy that came up with that 'reason' for not driving such a large content base from a database. good luck with that.

Comment: @Sky Sandars, totaly agree, this design is so unscalable they will end up redesigning it sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

Using pages to store the content will always create a problem when the number of pages is big. Since all the pages are hosted in the web server, in a near future you could have a problem. Maybe you could consider to use a WCM (Web Content Management) application instead of automatic page generation.

Answering you question, I believe you can inherit from one class (from pre-compiled pre-generated pages), but I think you will NOT have the new page pre-compiled. Just to highlight this is a guess, because I never did something like that.

Comment: That is an interesting thought, i will experiement. I hope it works as the new page is only refering to an already compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was "Project type" which was "Web Site" Project.
The web site project has dynamic compilation enabled using codedom, thats why it has App_code folder also which does not work in "Web Application" type Projects.
All the generated Pages where getting compiled whenever someone visited them. Since this issue I have converted to Web Application and have good results.

> Rumours are in VS2008 Microsoft
>   dropped Web Application project type
>   but later added it.